# Как расширить List в цикле?

Tags: java

Есть массив `String`, перевожу его в `List`, добавляю в цикл. Если в первом `if` срабатывает условие, то необходимо добавить в `List` символ. После цикл начинает проход уже с расширенного List'a. Почему-то если пытаюсь добавить символ, выкидывает ошибку. Почему?

```
String[] digits = String.valueOf(dividend).split("");
List<String> digitsList = Arrays.asList(digits); 
Integer mod;

for (int i = 0; i < digitsList.size(); i++) {

  String[] lines = result.toString().split("\\n");
  Integer previousReminder = lines[lines.length-1].length();
    reminder.append(digitsList.get(i));
    reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());
    mod = reminderNumber % divisor;

    if (reminderNumber < divisor && reminderNumber != previousReminder ) {
      reminderNumber = reminderNumber * 10;

      //digitsList.add("0"); выкидывает ошибку UnsupportedOperation

    }

    multiplyResult = reminderNumber / divisor * divisor;

    if (reminderNumber >= divisor || dividend < divisor && firstStep) {

      String lastReminder = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", "_" + Integer.toString(reminderNumber));
        result.append(lastReminder).append("\n");

        if(dividend < divisor) {
          multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 3) + "d", multiplyResult);
        }else {
          multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "d", multiplyResult);
        }
        result.append(multiply).append("\n");

        Integer tab = lastReminder.length() - calculateDigit(multiplyResult);
        result.append(createDivisor(multiplyResult, tab)).append("\n");

        quotient.append(reminderNumber / divisor);

        reminder.replace(0, reminder.length(), Integer.toString(mod));
        reminderNumber = Integer.parseInt(reminder.toString());

        firstStep = false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.

Обойти можно так:

```
List<String> digitsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(digits));
```

Comment: Начиная с Java 8 можно ещё и так: `List<String> digitsList = Arrays.stream(digits).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2):

Строка

```
List<String> digitsList = Arrays.asList(digits);
```

создает список фиксированного размера. Вернее она просто предоставляет доступ к массиву через интерфейс `List<>`.

А вам нужно создать свой список и добавить в него массив

```
List<String> digitsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(digits));
```